# Electrical transmission vs Chemical transmission

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, central-nervous-system, synapses

"The advantage of electrical transmission, apart from speed, is it can favour synchrony in firing. For example, in the brain stem a nucleus called the inferior olive can generate oscillations due to gap junctions."

Can somebody explain this idea? I do not understand the meaning of oscillations in this context. Do they mean that the neuron can send impulses and receive them at the same rate ? Is that what they're trying to put across ?

Source:Lecture Handouts

Comment: Please include a reference when you quote from a source; failing to do so is plagiarism.

Comment: Its from my lecture handouts